# Python read from text file unexpected results for find() function

Tags: python, file, text

I'm reading a text file generated by Praat : a .TextGrid.

```
fo=open(myFile)
fo.seek(0)
```

Then I have a loop over the lines of this file, in the course of which I need to identify some particular lines, so I evaluate a condition :

```
for line in fo:
(...)
foundName = line.find("name")
if foundName>0:
  <things>
```

My problem is that for some files, this works, and my processing is all right, but for some other files, although the string "name" belongs to some lines, it is never found. For each character individually, it works (e.g. find('n'), find('a'), etc), but not for strings (e.g. find('na').
For these files, I observed that it is True that
    line[x]=='n'
    line[x+2]=='a'
And Idon't understand why the contents of the file is "spread" this way...
How to overcome this ?  Is it a question of encoding ?

Answer (score 1):

It's an indentation issue. Your checking the last line  of the file and not all lines.

You should do

```
foundName = False
for line in fo:
     (...)
     foundName = foundName and (name in line)
if foundName:
  <things>
```